# error: variable 'QQmlComponent component' has initializer but incomplete type in Qt5

Tags: qt, qt5

i am playing with Exposing Attributes of C++ Types to QML in Qt5 based on this tutor http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html. when i run it i got this error on my issues pane **error: variable 'QQmlComponent component' has initializer but incomplete type** not only i have this error i have also this error the signal i have created using Q_PROPERTY is not detected

> C:\Users\Tekme\Documents\QtStuf\quick\QmlCpp\message.h:15: error: 'authorChanged' was not declared in this scope
>                emit authorChanged();
>                                   ^

my code is

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_H 
#define MESSAGE_H
#include <QObject>
class Message : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(QString author READ author WRITE setAuthor NOTIFY authorChanged)
public:
    void setAuthor(const QString &a) {
        if (a != m_author) {
            m_author = a;
            emit authorChanged();
        }
    }
    QString author() const {
        return m_author;
    }
private:
    QString m_author;
};
#endif
```

and in my main.cpp

```
#include "message.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QQmlEngine engine;
    Message msg;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("msg",&msg);
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
    component.create();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not including `QQmlComponent` header in your `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QQmlComponent>
```

You are also trying to emit a signal that you haven't declared yet. You should declare it in your `message.h` like this:

```
signals:
    void authorChanged();
```

Check [this example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/properties.html#a-simple-example).

Comment: thankssss. all my errors goes away thank you very much. the qt documentation is great but for beginners like me it is a little bit difficult.

Comment: @realtekme I do think that the tutorial you were following needs to be fixed. It has an example of a class that is missing a signal declaration.

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow, what do you mean accept the answer? your answer realy helped me and solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to add:

```
signals: 
  void authorChanged();
```

to your class like this:

```
  class Message : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(QString author READ author WRITE setAuthor NOTIFY authorChanged)
public:
    void setAuthor(const QString &a) {
        if (a != m_author) {
            m_author = a;
            emit authorChanged();
        }
    }
    QString author() const {
        return m_author;
    }
signals:
  void authorChanged();
private:
    QString m_author;
};
```

Comment: Hmm. I swear the other answer was not on my browser when I started answering. Although I did get a notification that an answer was posted after I had half finished.